# iPhone app settings readonly value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, plist

I have found this code that shows me how to insert some values for the iOS settings page on "system preferences".

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AppPrefs/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007799-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_7

The thing is that I want it only to insert the app version and some copyright text.

I have this Setting.bundle with the Root.plist insite it.

the plist have the "iPhone Settings Schema" dictionary just like the example and its working fine. But I am not able to set the copyright as the section footer like this image:

http://cl.ly/image/0v3b0O0Q0S2A

EDIT:
I have managed to set the readonly property for version, I was missing the "Default Value" key, since it does not add it for default.

But I still need to manage how to set the copyright string

Comment: Did my updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at this right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**title** is what you are looking for. From the [Apple Documentation on Preferences and Settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html):

> The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this type to display read-only preference values.

The copyright text is a `FooterText` in a `PSGroupSpecifier`. Have a look at [Group Element](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html) in the [Settings Application Schema Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference)